# Frozen on Splash Screen 22.04 + Gigabyte Motherboard + Onboard Audio

Tags: sound, gigabyte

I have just installed 22.04.1. When I boot, I get to the splash screen and seem to be frozen. No mouse or keyboard entries get any response.

Booting with nomodeset allows me to run from on board graphics, and the video card does not produce output.

I had a previous problem and thought it was related to the graphics card, so I did a re-install after disabling secure boot.

This appears to be where things start to go wrong, right before I am forced to reset.

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 systemd-udevd[369]: sdb3: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb3' failed with exit code 1.

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 systemd[1]: Finished Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 372 (plymouthd).

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Network.

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVI
DEO:00/input/input36

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input29

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sou
nd/card1/input30

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/c
ard1/input31

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b
.0/sound/card1/input32

Sep 22 17:03:51 kris-Z97X-Gaming-7 kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00
:1b.0/sound/card1/input33

Searches aren't giving me any hints. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a Nvidia graphics them 1. you should have selected the option to install 3rd party drivers when installing Ubuntu AND disabled Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: Thanks, but AMD graphics. I had tried amdgpu on a previous install attempt. This is a new install attempt with 3rd party drivers on and secure boot off.

Comment: With AMD graphics you need to do NOTHING. Secure Boot status is irrelevant for the open-source drivers it needs. Do NOT install anything else unless you have a very good reason (and know what you're doing).

Comment: I tried a clean install. I once believed the AMD 6600 was not yet supported. Now I am not certain. Anything other than nomodeset freezes at splash screen or boots to blank screen. For the installer I need to use safe graphics to avoid the same. If I get output on the graphics card, I get a frozen screen. If I only have onboard graphics, I can boot as expected.

Comment: Do I assume you are using the same live media each time? Did you verify the media when you made the boot device? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview Read that to do a verify of the ISO and remake the boot device. Personally I would re download the ISO first.